# how to solve angular material with mat-line-end

Tags: angular5, angular-material-5

can anyone explain why this can happen? when I use this command

```
<mat-list>
<mat-list-item>
  <img matListAvatar>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <p mat-line-end class="abu">Andika Ristian</p>
  <p mat-line class="abu">My Name Is</p>
   <img mat-line-end src="assets/imgs/panah.png">
</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

the result will be like this
[image]

but if i use the command like this with the same font as above.

```
<mat-list>
<mat-list-item>
  <img matListAvatar>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <p mat-line-end class="abu">Andika </p>
  <p mat-line-end class="abu">Ristian&nbsp;</p>
  <p mat-line class="abu">My Name Is</p>
   <img mat-line-end src="assets/imgs/panah.png">
</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

The result will be like this
[image]

I'm expected the result like the second picture but i think if i use the second command, it's not a solution to solve this. And for addition, i try to make the text align is right. the result will be like this
[image]

as the image above, the text is not same line with the other one. Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the width of your name.

```
.abu {
    width: 150px;
}
```